# tiny carousel add class to visible items pagination

Tags: jquery

My carousel has 2 items showing at a time, and there are 6 items in total.

Below the images there is a numbered selector but it only highlights one at a time.. How can I highlight (or add class to the page selectors) to the 2 images that are currently showing.. i.e. If I am viewing picture 4 and 5, then 1 2 3 "4 5" 6 - 4 & 5 would have a added class.

```
<div id="slider-code">
<a href="#" class="buttons prev">left</a>
<div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
        <li><img src="images/picture7.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture5.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture6.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture4.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture3.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture2.jpg"></li>                            
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" class="buttons next">right</a>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li><a rel="0" class="pagenum" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a rel="2" class="pagenum" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a rel="3" class="pagenum" href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a rel="4" class="pagenum" href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a rel="5" class="pagenum" href="#">6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I didn't include JS because the plugin (tiny carousel) has just a few simple options.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Not sure of what you're trying to do, but here's what I thought :

```
$('a').click( function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active').next('a').addClass('active');
});
```

This should active the clicked item and the next one.